# gvim: replace lower case words not starting with to with upper case

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to replace lower case words **not** starting with `[` to upper case, I think I am very close.

I have tried this approach: `:%s/\(\[\)\@![a-z]\+\>/\U&/g`
It's not quite right, and I have stared it down for too long - hence this 'phone a friend'.

I think it's matching the `[a-z]\+` regardless..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\@!` is a zero-width match at the *current* position, but you need a match *before* the current position. What `\[\@<![a-z]` (you don't need the grouping) says is *not an opening bracket and a lowercase character*; the second branch implies the first. Instead use `\@<!` to say *a lowercase character and before than not an opening bracket*. (That's also called **negative look-behind**.)

A second problem is that this will now match on the second character of a word, so it turns `[fix` to `[fIX`. One solution is to assert a start of a keyword with `\<`:

```
:%s/\[\@<!\<[a-z]\+\>/\U&/g
```

Another is to disallow lowercase characters (in addition to the opening bracket) before the word, too:

```
:%s/[[a-z]\@<!\<[a-z]\+\>/\U&/g
```

Comment: You can also use `\l` instead of `[a-z]`. See `:h /\l`.